Azure Logic App Unable To Set Variable (Times Out)
I have a logic app that among other things creates a variable.
When I run this logic app, the set to initialize the variable essentially times out (It never completes and just freezes).
When I check App Insights, I can see that this logic app is calling Azure Table Storage several times over and failing.

I'll note that my logic app itself does not require Table Storage and does not use it. So I'm assuming (Although I cannot find documentation for it) that variable used in Logic Apps are stored in Table Storage.
I'll note other requests from the same logic app also create various things in file shares, blob storage etc. And these seem to be created fine so the connection between Logic Apps and Storage is not completely broken, just some permissions have gone awry.

My connection string is stored in KeyVault. And it looks like so :
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=saXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountKey=XXXX
Which is taken directly from the storage account itself.
I can't seem to pinpoint why this is failing or how to debug it further.

I’m assuming this is LogicApps standard? Can you just confirm for us how you’ve configured the connection string from keyvault? Managed identity is setup too I assume? Has the storage account been setup with a private end point or something?

It is a standard. Connection string is configured via an Environment variable. Storage account is not behind a private endpoint.

Ok, and the app setting has a green tick indicating that it successfully retrieved the secret?

Yes. And it updates the file share and a couple of other things, but specifically it gets that 503 on Table Storage. I can now see that after doing nothing, it's now working. But I couldn't find any way to "debug" it because I don't really know what it's trying to do.
